# Search Function With Wildcard in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm teaching myself how to program Haskell, and I decided to make a find function in Haskell. What it does is it takes two strings, such as `"hello"` and `"he"`, and it counts how many times `"he"` appears in `"hello"`. In addition, it also uses the `*` character as a wildcard, so searching for `"he*o"` in `"hello"` will return `1`.

## Latest Update

This update used pattern matching and less guards, and also outputs 1 if `ssearch "blah" "*"`.

```
ssearch _ [] = 0
ssearch [] _ = 0
ssearch ('*':_) _ = error "no '*' allowed in hay"
ssearch _ ['*'] = 1
ssearch haystack ('*':needles) = ssearch haystack needles --removes '*', and then searches through hay for the char after the '*'
ssearch (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
  | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles + ssearch haystack (needle:needles) 
  | otherwise = ssearch haystack (needle:needles) 
    where
    search2 _ [] = 1
    search2 [] _ = 0
    search2 ('*':_) _ = error "no '*' allowed in hay" -- I need to declare this twice because search2 often jumps ahead of ssearch.
    search2  _ ['*'] = 1
    search2 haystack ('*':needles) = ssearch haystack needles
    search2 (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
      | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles 
          | otherwise = 0
```

## Update:

Thinking over [dave4420's comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/11824/4253), I decided to redo the entire algorithm. I think that it fixes most of the bugs.

```
ssearch _ [] = 0
ssearch [] _ = 0
ssearch (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
  | hay == '*' = error "no '*' allowed in hay" --no confusion with wildcard things
  | needle == '*' = ssearch (hay:haystack) needles --removes '*', and then searches through hay for the char after the '*'
  | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles + ssearch haystack (needle:needles) 
  | otherwise = ssearch haystack (needle:needles) 
    where
    search2 _ [] = 1
    search2 [] _ = 0
    search2 (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
      | hay == '*' = error "no '*' allowed in hay" -- I need to declare this twice because search2 often jumps ahead of ssearch.
      | (needle == '*') && (needles /= []) = ssearch (hay:haystack) needles 
      | (needle == '*') && (needles == []) = 1 
      | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles 
          | otherwise = 0
```

I'm wondering if there are still any bugs, and also, if there is any way I can improve this code.

### Old Code

```
search :: String -> String -> Integer
search x y = search1 x y y 0 -- n is set to 0, because nothing has been found yet :)
  where
    search1 :: String -> String -> String -> Integer -> Integer
    search1 _ _ [] n = n -- z can't be empty
    search1 x [] z n = search1 x z z (n+1) -- if y is empty but x isn't, it means the word was found, and y needs to be reset
    search1 [] _ _ n = n --end the program, bc if x is empty, the program has searched through the entire string
    search1 (x:xs) (y:ys) z n
      | x == '*' = error "you can not enter the character '*' in the first field: the '*' character is reserved for wildcard searches"
      | (y == '*') && ((head ys) == '*') = error "You can not include two '**' in a row, that messes up the wildcard operator"
      | x == y = search1 xs (ys) z n
      | (y == '*') && (ys /= []) = if (x == (head ys)) --this section is so search "hello" "h*llo" = 1
                        then search1 (x:xs) ys z n --if the string matches up with the rest of the string, excluding the '*', then redu the query, excluding the '*'
                       else search1 xs (y:ys) z n --} --otherwise keep on searching for the wildcard thing
      | (y == '*') && (ys == []) = n + 1 -- so search "hello" "*" = 1
      | otherwise = search1 xs z z n -- don't include (y:ys), otherwise search "hihe" "hhe" = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Yes, that's better.

Here is a version of your code that uses pattern matching more and guards less. I think it is clearer.

```
ssearch _ [] = 0
ssearch [] _ = 0
ssearch ('*' : _) _ = error "no '*' allowed in hay" --no confusion with wildcard things
ssearch haystack ('*' : needles) = ssearch haystack needles --removes '*', and then searches through hay for the char after the '*'
ssearch (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
  | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles + ssearch haystack (needle:needles) 
    where
    search2 _ [] = 1
    search2 [] _ = 0
    search2 ('*' : _) _ = error "no '*' allowed in hay" -- I need to declare this twice because search2 often jumps ahead of ssearch.
    search2 _ ['*'] = 1 
    search2 haystack ('*' : needles) = ssearch haystack needles 
    search2 (hay:haystack) (needle:needles)
      | needle == hay = search2 haystack needles 
    search2 _ _ = 0
ssearch (_:haystack) needles = ssearch haystack needles
```

There may still be bugs, but I can't see any :-)

### Original

1. It appears to be buggy.

   - I expect `search "hello" "he*lo"` to result in `1`, but it gives me `0`.
   - I expect `search "chanchance" "chance"` to result in `1`, but it gives me `0`.

   Also

   - `search "bobobob" "bob"` results in `2`, but perhaps it should result in `3`. Whether or not you want your function to count overlapping matches, you should document that it does/doesn't.

   You need to rethink your algorithm. (Edit: as you are learning Haskell, I presume you'd rather get your function working yourself, rather than have us spoon-feed you a working version.)
2. `x` and `y` are not very descriptive names. They are suitable when you are writing generic code, but this code is more specific. I would call them `haystack` and `needle` instead (from the common English phrase).
3. This line:

   ```
     | (y == '*') && ((head ys) == '*') = error "You can not include two '**' in a row, that messes up the wildcard operator"
   ```

   - `ys` may be `[]`, so `head ys` may be an error. You should be using pattern matching instead of `head` (and often instead of comparing to `[]` as well).
   - Why should a second `*` be an error anyway? The second `*` should successfully match a run of 0 characters, surely?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I am learning Haskell, so thanks for not spoiling the answer for me. I was wondering, by "You need to rethink your algorithm" do you mean I should rewrite the entire thing, or that I should debug the current algorithm?